# Groovy CSV File Compare

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy, but I've been a Java developer for a long time. I'm trying to run some stats and have been given two files to use and thought a Groovy script would work well for this.  What I'd like to do is determine which userIDs in one CSV file are not in the other CSV file.  For example:

all-users.csv:

```
joe
bobby
jane
fred
```

some-users.csv:

```
fred
jane
```

I'd like the stats on which userIDs are not contained in the 'some-users.csv' file. In this case, joe and bobby (2 users) are not in the some-users.csv.

I can't find any simple docs on loading a file's contents into a Collection and then doing a diff or compare.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: by _"CSV"_ do you mean an actual Comma Separated Values file, or just a file with one name per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have files with a single user per line, you can just do:

```
def allUsers = new File( '/tmp/all-users.csv' )
def someUsers = new File( '/tmp/some-users.csv' )
def diff = allUsers.text.tokenize( '\n' ) - someUsers.text.tokenize( '\n' )

assert diff == [ 'joe', 'bobby' ]
```

This can be generalised to take multiple files off an initial file by doing something like:

```
[ '/tmp/all-users.csv', '/tmp/some-users.csv' ].collect { new File( it ).text }
                                               .collect { it.tokenize( '\n' ) }
                                               .inject  { accum, e -> accum - e }
```

If you actually have a CSV, then you'll need to do some additional parsing (preferably [with a CSV parser](http://xlson.com/groovycsv/)) to get the list of names for each file

Answer (score 1):

You can load the files into memory with:

```
def allUsers= []    
new File("all-users.csv").eachLine { line -> allUsers.add(line) }
```

This is a pretty generic way of loading/processing all lines in a file.  Use cases: any additional parsing, creating and populating objects for each line, etc.

Then you can compute the difference between them with:

```
allUsers - someUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more research as well as the proposed solutions, here is what I came up with that seems to work the best:

```
def allUsers = new File("all-users.rtf").readLines()
def someUsers = new File("some-users.rtf").readLines()
def count = 0

allUsers.each {
    if (!someUsers.contains(it)) {
        count++
    }
}
println(count)
```